# How to Determine Cutoff Voltage and Full Charge Level for a 70Ah 12 V Lead Battery?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lead-acid

For a 70 Ah 12 V lead-acid battery with an unknown number of cells (likely 6 or 9 plates), what is the ideal cutoff voltage to maximize its lifespan? Additionally, at what voltage does this battery reach its full charge capacity?

I currently stop charging the battery when it reaches 13.8 V. Is this voltage safe for optimizing its lifespan(cycles life)?

Comment: This depends on the chemistry and number of cells, not the capacity. Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: it depends what you mean by 'optimise'

Comment: question update please review it thanks

Comment: A 12 volt lead-acid battery will have 6 cells, and likely many more than six or nine plates per cell.

Answer (score 0):

A [search for "ideal charge voltage for lead acid 12 V battery"](https://www.google.com/search?q=ideal+charge+voltage+for+12+V+lead+acid+battery) returns [this result](https://www.powerstream.com/SLA.htm#:%7E:text=Charging%20voltages%20range%20between%202.15,cannot%20break%20down%20the%20electrolyte.) that says "13.5 to 13.8 V at 25 °C".

A [search for "ideal cutoff voltage for 12 V lead acid battery"](https://www.google.com/search?q=ideal+cutoff+voltage+for+12+V+lead+acid+battery) returns [this result](https://www.kendrickastro.com/lvc.html#:%7E:text=The%20truth%20is%20that%20any,charge%2C%20will%20ruin%20the%20battery.) that says "any lead acid battery, be it a Gel Cell, AGM or flooded batteries such as DCBs, should be cut-off at 11.6 volts.".

Answer (score 0):

For led-acid chemistry, it’s 2.2 volts nominal per cell.  In monoblocks that means 6 cells.  Number of plates is probably irrelevant to your question.

Any given specific manufacturer’s product will advise exact cell voltage for low-charge and high/full-charge cut-off thresholds.

Given (a) the need to ensure all cells within a monoblock are fully recharged, and (b) lead-acid’s forgiving tolerance to over-voltage during recharge (tho not so high that you experience high levels of out-gassing of H2), it’s much easier to attain 100% charge on all cells by allowing per-cell voltage to rise to relatively high levels, above 14 volts.  This strategy is even formalised with periodic ‘cell refresh’ and ‘rejuvenation’ recharge cycles, to help with other lead-acid chemistry quirks.

Best cell longevity is achieved by not **discharging* cells below datasheet-specified states-of-charge, often in the realm of 50%, maybe not even that low(!!).  This has been lead-acid’s Achilles Heel since its beginning, over a century ago.  There’s a major class of lead-acid batteries dedicated to this reality of almost never being deeply discharged, but also capable of brief very high current output: the ones used for starting IC engines in cars, trucks, generators, etc.

This is quite different to newer Lithium rechargable chemistry, which can tolerate much lower states-of-charge, but which have much stricter limits on maximum cell voltage, making the need to perform ‘balanced cell charging’ necessary, in order to keep all cells in a series string as close in state-of-charge as possible (see other answers in my history detailing this).

Comment: Is it okay if I charge my battery at 13.8 volts? I checked, and it has 6 cells mono block.

Comment: How i determine my battery is overcharged?

Comment: Did you miss the 2nd sentence?  13.8V recharge maximum voltage will probably get the job done, but ***it's the datasheet for that brand and model battery you need to consult***.  There's several types of lead-acid, and they all have their own care-&-feeding constraints.
https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-201-how-does-the-lead-acid-battery-work

Comment: How’s your situation going, @JOHN ?  If an answer here was correct and addressed your situation, we’d appreciate you marking it ‘answered’.